# How to create a file in the resources folder in Kotlin, Gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In a completely fresh project, I want to create a single file `myFile.json` inside the `src/main/resources/` folder at run time.

For reading a file, I need to do some config in the `build.gradle.kts` file, but I can't find anything on what to do for creating a file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your `build.gradle.kts` file look like? Do you want to create the file during a Gradle task? Do you want to read it during a Gradle task or from your projects code?

Comment: Edited the main post - I want to do it at run time from the kotlin file.

Comment: You usually don't create a file at runtime in the *sources* of your code, and that folder you specified is there. So maybe you can describe the purpose of that file at that specific position to get some advice. Not even the class files that are used to run the program are at that location, the source files don't even have to be available to execute your code.

Comment: I want to know what the equivalent of `touch myFile.json` or python's 
with open("myFile.json", "w") as file:
    file.write("{}")

Answer (score 0):

1. @Endzeit has asked what have you tried so far.  Please share the code.
2. Like @cyberbrain says - are you sure you want to write to resources folder?

Here is code that writes back to where the source resources folder is:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // Let's assume you want your project to be portable, so you don't
    // want to use absolute file paths.
    // Find out where your IDE will launch the project from.  Normally this is
    // the root folder of the whole project.  Find out with this: the `canonicalPath` will help:
    val workingFolder = File(".")
    println("workingFolder=${workingFolder.canonicalPath}")

    // Define the folder you want to write in to
    // this will vary especially if you have a nested project structure
    // IntelliJ under the Edit > Copy Path menu option will help you find the resources
    // relative location
    val parentFolder = File("src/main/resources")
    println("parentFolder=${parentFolder.canonicalPath}")
    require(parentFolder.exists())
    val outFile = File(parentFolder, "test.txt")
    outFile.printWriter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).use {
        it.println("Hello world")
    }
    println("Wrote to ${outFile.canonicalPath}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the directory `src/main/resources/` exists:

```
val f = File("src/main/resources/myFile.json")
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    f.createNewFile()  // This is the answer to the question
    f.printWriter().use { out ->
        out.println("{}")
    }
}
```